# MLE of a weighted sum of Poisson variables

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution

I have n Poisson random variables with the same parameter $\lambda$:  $x_i\sim POI(\lambda)$.
I know that $\frac{\sum(x_i)}{n}$ is a MLE of $\lambda$.

My question is, observing the weighted sum of these Poisson variables $X=\sum \alpha_i x_i$, is the MLE of $\lambda$ equal to $\frac{X}{\sum \alpha_i}$?

If no, only knowing the sum $X$ and these weights $\alpha_i$, how do we get the MLE for $\lambda$?

Comment: This is an extremely complicated problem in general because for most choices of the $\alpha_i$ there is a *unique* solution for the $x_i$ in terms of $X$ but it is not simple to write down.  For instance, consider $n=2$ with $\alpha_1=1$ and $\alpha_2=\pi:$ necessarily $X = j + k\pi$ for some integers $j$ and $k$ and, unless $X=0,$ obviously $x_1=j$ and $x_2=k.$  What can you tell us about the values of the $\alpha_i$?  Could you explain how this observation process arises?

Comment: Cross-posted: [MLE of weighted sum of Poisson variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4690692/mle-of-weighted-sum-of-poisson-variables)

Comment: @User1865345 Sorry for the cross-posting. I am not very familiar with this forum. I will close that question soon.

Answer (score 1):

$X/\sum{\alpha_i}$ is the method of moments estimator of $\lambda$ and (usually) would be a good starting value in an iterative algorithm to find the maximum likelihood estimator.

For the maximum likelihood estimator one, of course, would need to find the likelihood.  That requires finding all combinations of $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i$ equals $X$.

I'm sure this can be done in *R* but for me it's easier done in *Mathematica*.  Suppose $n=3$:

```
alpha = {12, 3, 1};
x = {x1, x2, x3};
X = 16;
```

Now find all of the possible triplets of `x` that satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i=X$:

```
sol = x /. Solve[X == alpha . x, x, NonNegativeIntegers]
(* {{0, 0, 16}, {0, 1, 13}, {0, 2, 10}, {0, 3, 7}, {0, 4, 4}, 
    {0, 5, 1}, {1, 0, 4}, {1, 1, 1}} *)
```

Find the likelihood by summing up all of the triplet probabilities:

```
likelihood = Total[Exp[-Length[a] lambda] lambda^Total[#]/(#[[1]]! #[[2]]! #[[3]]!) & /@ sol] // Simplify
```

$$\frac{e^{-3 \lambda } \lambda ^3 \left(\lambda ^{13}+3360 \lambda ^{11}+2882880 \lambda ^9+691891200 \lambda ^7+36324288000 \lambda ^5+174356582400 \lambda ^3+871782912000 \lambda ^2+20922789888000\right)}{20922789888000}$$

Find the value of $\lambda$ that maximizes the likelihood:

```
mle = FindMaximum[Log[Total[likelihood]], {{lambda, X/Total[alpha]}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
(* {-2.94728411728903585719176910466, {lambda -> 1.04081006682956426205089024036}}
```

The value 1.04081006682956426205089024036 is pretty close to the method of moments estimate of $16/(12+3+1)=1$.

Comment: To make this work consistently one would need to "rationalize" (or make "exact") the values of $X$ and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ so that there is no round-off error when determining the integer values of $x_1,\ldots,x_2$.